# Save many images with nodejs fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fetch

I am tring to download around 20.000 images from a website by scraping it.
(I am authorized by the owner)

The path of the image is composed like this:
VolumeId/ChapterId/PageId.jpg

There are around 100 volumes, and every volume has x chapters, and every chapter has y pages.

In the database I have stored for every volume the number of chapters, but i don't have
the number of pages, so I have to navigate to the image url and check if it exists.

I know for sure that there are less than 30 pages per chapter so I did something like this:

```js
let exists = true;
for (let i = 0; i < 30 && exists; i++) {
  fetch(`imgUrl/${i}.jpg`)
    .then(data => {
      if (data.ok)
        return data.arrayBuffer();
      else
        exists = false;
    .then(arrayBuffer => {
      if (exists) {
        let buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer );

        if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, imgPath))) {
          fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, imgPath), {
            recursive: true,
          });
        }

        fs.writeFile(
          path.join(__dirname, imgPath + "/" + img + ".jpg"),
          buffer,
          (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
          }
        );
      }
    });
}
```

**The problem:**

The problem is that the loop does not wait for the image to be fetched and saved locally.
I have tried with async/await and promises (I think I have implemented them wrong)

Is there a better way to download a large quantity of data? Maybe with streams?

Comment: `I have tried with async/await` <-- Can you please post what you have tried so far using async/await?

Comment: you can use the `fs` module's synchronous api [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) instead of the callback api like you are here. However, a better approach would be to use async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a little bit complicated to implement your code with just async/await and at the same time assure the "exists" condition between iterations, I suggest you use a class that implements an async iterator, refer to the official documentation for more details, the following code achieve what you are looking for (note: the code snippet you provided didn't show where "imgPath" is coming from so just fix my code accordingly)  :

```
class FetchImages {
    constructor(urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.index = 0;
    }

    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        const urlsIterator = this.urls[Symbol.iterator]();
        return {
            async next() {
                if (++index == 30) {
                    return {
                        done: true
                    };
                }
                const iteratorResult = urlsIterator.next();
                if (iteratorResult.done) {
                    return { done: true };
                }
                const url = iteratorResult.value;
                try {
                    let response = await fetch(url);
                    let data;
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        data = await response.arrayBuffer();
                    } else {
                       // equivalent to exists == false, exit condition of the iterator
                        
                        return {
                            done: true
                        };
                    };

                    let buffer = Buffer.from(data);

                    if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, imgPath))) {
                        fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, imgPath), {
                            recursive: true,
                        });
                    }
                    fs.writeFileSync(
                        path.join(__dirname, imgPath),
                        buffer,
                    );
                    return {
                        done: false,
                        value: imgPath
                    };

                } catch (err) {
                    return {
                        done: false,
                        value: err.message
                    };
                }

            } 
        }
    }
}

(async function () {
    const fetchImages = new FetchImages(urls);
    for await (const fetchImage of fetchImages) {
        // check status of each fetch
        console.log(fetchImage);
    }
})();
```